# What is the default property type editor for enums?

Tags: c#, enums, custom-controls, properties, uitypeeditor

I have a property of type "Type" and need to assign an enum type editor to it.

Thanks

Comment: not getting you can you please explain ?

Comment: How can I assign an enum editor to this property? The enum is build dynamically via enum builder. How can I use a combo box for the property editor?

public Type Test
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

Comment: I need to show the enum values of a dynamically created enum type in a combo box at the property editor for the custom control.

Comment: The property editor will show design time values, how are you dynamically creating an enum?

Comment: Since `Type` is not an enum, what would the purpose of an enum UITypeEditor be here? A enum UITypeEditor can only be active on an enum property.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Enum.GetNames
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getnames.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See my blog article which explains how one can put more information on an enum then reflect off of it to extract it (thought as of this writing it is unclear on how the enums are being *generated*):

[C# Using Extended Attribute Information on Objects](http://omegacoder.com/?p=28)

Then see a related blog article I wrote on using a Tuple to load combobox with information

[C#: How to Load a Winform ComboBox or ListBox and have a Unique Value Associated with the Selected Item](http://omegacoder.com/?p=701)

HTH